# Angular 1.5 : Access parent component without knowing the name of the parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I am working on 2 components using Angular 1.5.

I want to access the parent from the child, and I managed to do it using :

```
require: {
    parent: '^parentCmp'
}
```

The thing is, I would like to do the same, but without "fixing" the parent as "parentCmp", since it won't always be this component I'll have as a parent.

Thanks.

Comment: Not really what you're asking for, but it can maybe help : if you're using $scope, inside the child you can still use $scope.$parent.

Comment: I don't think is ok to know about the parent in this way. Require is used to inject the component controller anyway, so you might as well provide a binding for the parent to provide the instance for you. But if the communication is based on a contract then define an interface and pass an object from the parent to the child holding all the required information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do it :) But if you have to, you can pass it as regular `binding`. Child component:

```
bindings: {
    parent: '<'
}
```

And in parent template (I presume that you use `$ctrl` alias for `controller`, if it's not true use name you provide):

```
<child-component
    parent="$ctrl"
>
</child-component>
```

Comment: That's a solution I figured out but it doesn't seem right, I'm putting this as the answer but I think there's a design flaw if it's needed.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Seems like this is the simplest and most flexible solution